# Fill missing data in a linear model

Tags: kotlin, math

I have the following `val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, null, null, 6, 7)` I'd like to fill the null value for the following result: `listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`

I couldn't find any method doing this in Kotlin, do you guys have an idea?

EDIT: I'm adding more details, the list will always have a beginning element and an ending element (ie no list as `listOf(null, 2 ,3)` or `listOf(1, 2, null)`) I preprocess this.

In my example I gave Integer element but it could be Float or Double

Comment: How do you decide what value to put instead of nulls exactly? Do you want to do a linear regression on the values and then fill accordingly? What if it only has null values?

Comment: Hello, yes linear regression, I put an example of Integer but it could be a list of Float or Double. If only nulls we can ignore, my list will always have a beginning element and an ending element

Comment: Then I guess you won't find something out of the box, but there are probably statistics libraries out there that could perform the linear regression, or you could implement your own. If you have exact values (not imprecise samples), you might not need a true linear regression and could instead just use the first and last value to compute your equation and then fill in the blanks. Is that what you need help with?

Comment: Indeed in the end I've done a coefficient between the first and last value. I'm trying to optimize it a little bit more before posting it here. I can post it here if you'd like to see/propose a refacto

Comment: There are a lot of ways you might choose to fill those values in.  The example you gave might not be the best for non-trivial problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```kotlin
inline fun <T>List<T?>.replaceIfNull(block:(T) -> T) : List<T>{
    val temp = mutableListOf<T>()
    for((index, element) in this.withIndex()){
        if(element == null){
            temp.add(block(this[index - 1] ?: temp[index - 1]))
        } else {
            temp.add(element)
        }
    }
    return temp
}


fun main() {
   val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, null, null, 6, 7) 
   val foo = list.replaceIfNull { nonNullValue ->
       nonNullValue + 1
   }
   println(foo) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
}
```

##### EDIT

**Linear Model**

```kotlin
fun <T:Number>List<T?>.interpolate() : List<Double> {
        val temp = mutableListOf<Double>()
        var nullCounter = 0
        this.forEach { element ->
            if(element != null){
                val formatedElement = element.format()
                temp.add(formatedElement)
                if(nullCounter > 0){
                   var difference = (formatedElement - temp[temp.size - 2]) / (nullCounter + 1)
                   for(i in 0..nullCounter - 1){
                       val newElement = (temp[temp.size - 2] + difference).format()
                       temp.add((temp.size - 1), newElement)
                   }
                }
               
                nullCounter = 0
            }
            element ?: nullCounter++
        }
        
        return temp
    }
```

test: https://pl.kotl.in/rpbDZ8zkq

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, OP wants to perform a linear regression to fill in the blanks

Comment: @Joffrey you're right , i'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

There's no way on how to decide what number you want to replace with `null`.

Considering what if `listOf(1, null, null)` or `listOf(null, 2, null)`.

If you know exactly what a list needs to be, you might use `IntProgression` or `IntRange` instead.

```
// 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
val list1 = IntRange(1, 7).toList()

// 1, 3, 5, 7
val list1 = IntProgression(1, 7, 2).toList()
```

Comment: I know the beginning and the end. the list could be a list of Float as well

Comment: It's same. Use `ClosedDoubleRange` or `ClosedFloatRange` even `ClosedRange` interface.

Comment: Both these class are private and doesn't correspond to my question

Comment: @ryoii this has nothing to do with the question, OP wants to perform a linear regression to fill in the blanks

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to do a simple function that could interpolate. There is room for improvement.

```kotlin
private fun Double.format(): String = DecimalFormat("#.##").format(this)

private fun List<*>.findNonNullIndex(currentIndex: Int, ascending: Boolean = true): Int {
    for (i in currentIndex..lastIndex step if(ascending) 1 else -1) {
        if(getOrNull(i) != null) return i
    }
    return currentIndex
}

fun interpolate(list: MutableList<Double>) {
    println("initial : $list")
    list.forEachIndexed { index, i ->
        if(i == null) {
            val nonNullIndex = list.findNonNullIndex(index)
            val difference = list[nonNullIndex]?.minus(list[index-1] ?: return) ?: return
            val coefficient = difference.div((nonNullIndex - index) + 1)
            for(j in index until nonNullIndex) {
                list[j] = (list[j-1]?.plus(coefficient))?.format()?.toDouble()
            }
        }
    }
    println("result: $list")
}

interpolate(mutableListOf(1.0, null, null, null, 1.4, null, 1.5, 1.7))
```

link: https://pl.kotl.in/HcqoB8qFL

Comment: Oh so you *don't* want a linear model for the whole list, then? I think I misunderstood your goal here. You just want the holes to be filled evenly between the last non-null value and the next non-null value, but you don't expect a consistent coefficient for the whole list. I thought you wanted a linear regression, but you just want linear interpolation. My bad

Comment: I don't quite get why you use double formatting to then re-parse it, this is pretty inefficient, what's the goal?

Comment: The reformat is indeed useless, I kept it for a nicer println()

Comment: @Biscuit you could try my solution on my edited answer, but idk if it is better or not